# XPath based on sibling attribute

Tags: html, xml, xpath

I am looking to find the best way to form a XPath for any table record, based on a `b` tag in the `div` above the table.

I have about 13 tables on this page, however I cannot access any tables other than the first table record, because none of the tables have unique identifiers. The only uniqueness is located in the within the div directly above the table records, which I am trying to utilize.

For instance, trying to get the table XPath following `TEST RECORD 2`. Could anyone offer any assistance?

```
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <b>TEST RECORD 1</b> (T1)
        <span class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-cog"></i></span>
        <br>
        <small class="muted"></small>
    </div>
    <table class="table table-condensed">...</table>

    <div class="panel-heading">
        <b>TEST RECORD 2</b> (T2)
        <span class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-cog"></i></span>
        <br>
        <small class="muted"></small>
    </div>
    <table class="table table-condensed">...</table>
```

Just to end the question, I am not looking to using any indexed solutions. I am only looking to pass in the `b` tag text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This XPath,

```
//div[b = 'TEST RECORD 2']/following-sibling::table[1]
```

will select the immediately following `table` sibling of the `div` element with a child `b` element whose string value is `'TEST RECORD 2'`.